# use the valid part of xml present in the broken xml

Tags: c, libxml2

hi how to use the valid part of an xml present inside a broken xml

Ex: <nodea>
 <nodeb>DATA</nodeb 
 <nodec> DATA </nodec>

at above since the nodea is not getting closed so this is a broken xml,but the nodeb & nodec are the valid Xmls present inside nodea. so can i retrive the data inside them or not using libxml2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to fix the file by a heuristical hack before you parse it.

```
$ cat broken.xml 
<nodea>
<nodeb>DATA</nodeb 
<nodec> DATA </nodec>
$ < broken.xml sed 's%</nodeb[^>]%</nodeb>%'
<nodea>
<nodeb>DATA</nodeb>
<nodec> DATA </nodec>
```